# Instagram embed not working on some mobile devices

Tags: android-webview, embed, wkwebview, instagram-api

It loads the placeholder "View this post on Instagram" instead embedded media. Standard Instagram embed code is used, and this happens both in Chrome and Firefox browsers on the same device. Interesting, it is happening on Android and iOS, but only on small number of devices I test.

Any idea?

[image: Instagram embed]

Comment: Make sure you append "http:" (this is by default missing) to the url you get from Instagram embed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue using a WKWebView in iOS 12.  The solution that worked for me was to use an iframe with the standard link with "/embed" as the last path element, rather than the embed code provided by Instagram.  Example from a viewDidLoad():

```
let embed = "<iframe src=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/BwdGxDGAOcP/embed\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" allowtransparency=\"true\"></iframe>"
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
let webview = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: config)
webview.uiDelegate = self
view = webview
webview.loadHTMLString(embed, baseURL: nil)
```